# Using definitive article with "number of"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, articles, definite-article, singular-vs-plural

Should I use an article with `limited number of`

> This shop is visited by a limited number of customers.

Or,

> This shop is visited by limited number of customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to show this by examples from literature. I've looked for **limited number of**, and all results have **a** or **the** article.

Examples with **a** article:

> "What you are experiencing is what we'd call undifferentiated schizophrenia, meaning you're displaying **a limited number of** the primary symptoms —in your case, seeing visions and hearing voices. 
>     "While space itself is vast, there are **a limited number of** settled planets, and even fewer which have substantial space traffic in and out. 
>     (Course open to **a limited number of** students.)
>     After all, the galaxy has room for only **a limited number of** multibillionaires--which meant that the vast majority of those around him at any given time had far less money than he, and had at least some interest in altering what they perceived as. an unnatural imbalance. 
>     After all, we’re dealing with **a limited number of** possible suspects. 
>     And I thought, “That’s terrible, because you only have **a limited number of** responses. 
>     And if they were going to hit New Sydney, they had **a limited number of** options.
>     Hannah meanwhile held the remaining three at gunpoint, so perhaps it was Braddock’s idea to keep **a limited number of** hostages. 
>     He could have transported down here from the attack ship but, being only able to transport himself and **a limited number of** items through U-space, he required this shuttle. 
>     He could only make **a limited number of** choices that would prove most beneficial in the long, long run.
>     Imagine twelve cramped space vehicles filled with hundreds of emotionally crazed passengers and **a limited number of** atmospheric suits. 
>     In **a limited number of** cases, chiefly because of the risk of prejudicing a possible prosecution, no reference can be made to them at all. 
>     In addition to its conventional weapons, the Ronald Reagan is the first aircraft carrier in more than a decade to carry **a limited number of** nuclear warheads, a policy change dictated by Russia’s and China’s recent push in the nuclear arms race, spurred on by United States insistence on moving ahead with its own Missile Defense Shield.
>     It would possess only **a limited number of** species and only those that human beings wanted, or couldn’t help introducing—”
>     Once they were with **a limited number of** people for a period of time, they intuitively sensed if someone was missing.
>     She possessed **a limited number of** bullets. 
>     Still, there would only be fodder for **a limited number of** horses, mules, and camels. 
>     The spider web extended to infinity in every direction: the space-time continuum represented as a flat surface for those simple humans who could visualize only **a limited number of** dimensions.
>     There were **a limited number of** hospitals in Buffalo. 
>     There were **a limited number of** options, when faced with the daunting and expensive task of pushing a road through mountains. 
>     This was like one of those infuriating parlour games where one had only **a limited number of** questions to ascertain whether the person who was It was Wellington, the vicar or the Empress Josephine.
>     What's more, the questions have to be the kind that can be put into **a limited number of** symbols. 
>     ‘Because no more are being produced, there’s only **a limited number of** reifications who can come here for either a cure or their physical destruction by the virus, so eventually pilgrimages by those you find distasteful will dwindle. 
>     “Bartholomew informed me there were **a limited number of** families with the right kind of magic to be guardsmen—abilities that passed down father to son. 
>     “Granted, Rainey Days’ records show that the samples were only distributed in **a limited number of** venues, but it does seem suspicious. 
>     “There are **a limited number of** planets in this sector of the Galaxy that possess the physical characteristics associated with habitability, and almost all of them must be not only inhabitable, but inhabited, and therefore well known to you. 
>   **A very limited number of** births will be authorized.

Examples with **the** aricle (it can depend on context):

> It was all exactly as Erebus required, for those reserve forces, those ECS fleets, were easy to locate in **the limited number of** solar systems with sufficient industrialization to support them. 
>   It’s all very stressful and crowded in the tiny teachers’ room as we scramble for **the limited number of** seats, sometimes ending up writing our files while leaning against the file cabinet that other teachers keep needing to use or sitting on someone’s lap. 
>   She had two more courses at a community college before she could transfer to the University of Florida and start the real competition for **the limited number of** spots in their veterinary medicine program. 
>   Some of the people aboard went down with the ship rather than deprive someone else of a seat in **the very limited number of** lifeboats. 
>   Spike had never taken a mate, never had a cub, and with **the limited number of** Shifter females available, Spike thought he never would.
>   Wherever she was, she took it upon herself to supervise her nephew and niece from a distance, by writing regularly to advise them on their conduct, their choice of companions, and **the limited number of** families with whom it was proper for them to associate. 
>   "Yes, but in a small town, one can't afford to offend **the limited number of** vendors available," I pointed out.

So my conclusion: you should use an article with ***"limited number of"***.

But be careful, this is just examples from literature not a hard authoritative position!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need use an article in this case.

Below you can see Google Ngram chart about this situation:

[image: Ngram Viewer]